# How to add canned CSS text from an ajax query to Angular 2 app?

Tags: css, ajax, angular, typescript2.0

How do I insert a blob of CSS text I get back from the backend into my component?

I tried using the DOMSanitizer's bypassSecurityTrustHtml, but although the html was fine otherwise, any style tags got escaped.

Example:

```
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'the-app',
  template: `
     <div [innerHtml]="myHtml"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    // the text would actually be from the database...
    this.myHtml = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<div><style>.myClass{color: red;}</style><div>THIS SHOWS FINE</div></div>') ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would a regular Ajax call not work? If you make a regular Ajax call inside your angular application what issues do you run into?

Comment: Thanks, not a problem with ajax, I have updated the question.

Comment: Then no need for any of that info.

Comment: Yeah, was in a rush and worded it poorly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works.  I find it oddly inconsistent with the escaping that occurs with my original post though.

```typescript
import {Renderer, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'the-app',
  template: `
     <div #myRef></div>
     <div class=".junkClass">MAKE ME BLUE</div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('myRef') myReference: ElementRef;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        let tempElement = this.renderer.createElement(this.myReference.nativeElement, 'div');
        tempElement.innerHTML = '<style type="text/css">.junkClass { color: blue;}</style>';

    }
}
```